# Can't Access $__POST values in update_post_meta() WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to update form field values but i can't, what i'm trying to do is get the values from the custom fields and save it but it returns nothing when saved I tried many solutions but didn't work and i tried echo out the $__POST and it's empty i think the problem lies in $__POST but i don't know why it isn't getting any data.

```
//theme shop menu
class BakentakeShopMenu{
    function __construct(){
        //register shop menu custom post type
        add_action( 'init', array($this,'create_menuitem_cpt'), 0 );
        //register custom fields for shop menu post type
        add_action("add_meta_boxes",[$this,'shop_items_custom_fields']);
        
        add_action('save_post',[$this,'save_shop_items_fields']);
    }

// Register Custom Post Type Menu Item
function create_menuitem_cpt() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Menu Items', 'Post Type General Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Menu Item', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'textdomain' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Menu Items', 'Admin Menu text', 'textdomain' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'Menu Item', 'Add New on Toolbar', 'textdomain' ),
        'archives' => __( 'Menu Item Archives', 'textdomain' ),
        'attributes' => __( 'Menu Item Attributes', 'textdomain' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Menu Item:', 'textdomain' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Menu Items', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New', 'textdomain' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'view_items' => __( 'View Menu Items', 'textdomain' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found', 'textdomain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'textdomain' ),
        'featured_image' => __( 'Featured Image', 'textdomain' ),
        'set_featured_image' => __( 'Set featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'use_featured_image' => __( 'Use as featured image', 'textdomain' ),
        'insert_into_item' => __( 'Insert into Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list' => __( 'Menu Items list', 'textdomain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Menu Items list navigation', 'textdomain' ),
        'filter_items_list' => __( 'Filter Menu Items list', 'textdomain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label' => __( 'Menu Item', 'textdomain' ),
        'description' => __( '', 'textdomain' ),
        'labels' => $labels,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-cart',
        'supports' => array('thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields'),
        'taxonomies' => array(),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
    );
    register_post_type( 'menuitem', $args );
}

    //add custom field settings
    function shop_items_custom_fields(){
        add_meta_box(
            'shop_item',
            'shop items',
            array($this,'shop_items_config'),
            'menuitem',
            'normal',
            'low',
            ''

        );
    }
    // save custom field values 
    function save_shop_items_fields($post_id ){
            update_post_meta(
                $post_id ,
                "item_name_value",
                $__POST['itemname']
            );
    }   

    //custom fields config
    function shop_items_config($post_id){
        $value = get_post_meta($post_id,'item_name_value',true);
        ?>
        <form action = "" method="POST">
            <div class="shop-items-form">
                <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                    <label for="item-name">Item Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="itemname" value="<?php echo $value ?>"/>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                    <label for="item-description">Item Description</label>
                    <textarea name="item-description"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-items-form-field__wraper">
                    <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                        <label for="itemPrice">Item Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="itemPrice"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                        <label for="discount-price">Discount Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discountName"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="shop-items-form-field">
                    <label for="discount-price">Add Item Image</label>
                    <input type="file" name="itemImage"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <?php
    }
};

new BakentakeShopMenu;
```

Comment: Change `$__POST` to `$_POST` (single underscore)

Comment: this is the answer thanks

Comment: Sweet, happy to help!